# Avoid back button after login in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I was looking for a specific Spring feature that can prevent user from going back to a restricted area, using the back button, after the logout. I dind't find anything.

Is there a specific Spring feature to handle my issue or I should  use `response.setHeader(.....` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct feature in spring , you can use `interceptor` to do this work . same as your servlet filters, set the `cacheSeconds` to 0

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

this explains [`WebContentInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/WebContentInterceptor.html) . and also [nice expalanation](http://devjav.com/spring-security-browser-back-button/) here.

Comment: Hi man, thank you for your help. I edited your code and put it into my configuration file. It seems to work. I'd like to ask you another question: I'm using two different interceptors, yours and one that I created extending HandlerInterceptorAdapter. They seems to work well togheter. Do you know if there are specific problems to handle when using many interceptors togheter?

Comment: No matters with the number of interceptors , you can put them in the `<list>` tags